# Bajaj discover 125(2011model) runs like always giving reserve fuel warning even when fuel is sufficient

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-consumption, carburetor, mileage, bajaj

I have Bajaj Discover 125 (2011) model which has always been taken care by me.    as i dont ride bike much it only ran upto 20,000 km till now in plains. (Punjab).   Everything was  fine and the bike was giving me 70+ kmpl mileage on higway and 60+ kmpl in local . An i was super happy . But from past 2-3 months problem started . Bike started getting off  in crucial time while driving when i slow down the race from 40 km/h to down.   And then wont start. After number of attempts and putting the  fuel selector knob on reserve mode it some how starts but  keeps on giving me  the shaky ride (just like it happens in low fuel  warning) and engine  can still turn   off any time. Even though i have enough fuel. I went to various local mechanics the cleaned the  carburettor and  claimed to set the air fuel mixture ratio well. But after that it didn't give me good mileage. Which reduced to only 35-40kmpl . 
Now my observations regarding the bike. I feel the fuel reserve mechanism could be faulty  and wrongly indicates the low fuel condition because  my fuel meter still shows enough fuel.  Local mechanics dont know much. Someone please help

Comment: There could be multiple reasons like clogged air filter,faulty spark plugs or faulty fuel knob.i would advise get it inspected at authorised bajaj service station.

Answer (score 1):

Check the float mechanism inside the gas tank and it's connection. Make sure it is working properly. Also check the fuses of course.

If all that checks out follow the leads from the leveler all the way through - it has to be grounding out somewhere or totally cut.

If everything checks out I'd buy a new float mechanism and hook it up with all new leads going where they're supposed to be going...good luck